# How to insert initial data in MongoDB on app start?

Tags: express, mongoose

I am using express and mongoose. I want to insert some data in MongoDB on server start. only if data is not there. 
Is there any module that I can use?

Comment: Have you gone through https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-data-seed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *need* an external module to do that. You know the data you want, you know how your data is structured, and you can easily do it yourself.

Simply declare your seeding logic in your main `app.js` **or** in an external file and import it into the main `app.js` file:

```
const MyModel = require("./models/my-model");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();

async function mySeeder() {
    const data = await MyModel.find({...}).exec();
    if (data.length !== 0) {
        // Data exists, no need to seed.
        return;
    }
    const seed = new MyModel({...});

    // some other seed logic
    // ...

    await seed.save()
}


mySeeder();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Hello World!"));
```